# Function a subset of a group?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

a question I had troubles with:

Let $X, Y$ be sets and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a function.

Prove that $f(f^{-1}(B))\subset B$ for every $B\subset Y$.

So, in this case is it that the values that what $f(f^{-1}(B))$ 'returns' consists of $B$'s elements? Because I'm not sure what it means it equals to the set $B$.

If that's the picture, I can understand why it is... I'm just not sure how to prove it with formality.

Many thanks!

Edit: I have written the original question wrong, and thus a false statement. I edited and fixed it. Sorry and thanks for any help!

Comment: The statement is wrong. Consider $X=Y=\mathbb N$ and $f(x)=1$ and $B=\{1, 2\}$.

Comment: Emberassing, I got two question mixed up in one. I edited it, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

For the corrected question, just write up the definitions of $f^{-1}(B)$ and $f(C)$ for subsets $C\subseteq X,\ B\subseteq Y$, they are:
$$f^{-1}(B)=\{x\in X\,\mid\, f(x)\in B\} \\
f(C)=\{f(c)\,\mid\,c\in C\}\,,$$
and combine them to arrive that $f(C)\subseteq B\ $ if $\ C=f^{-1}(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly false. For example, let $X=Y=\Bbb{R}$, and let $f$ be the constant function $f(x)=1$. Then taking $B=\Bbb{R}$, we have $f(f^{-1}(B))=f(\Bbb{R})=\{ 1\} \neq \Bbb{R}=B$.

Comment: Emberassing, I got two question mixed up in one. I edited it, sorry!